# Templated member function and inheritence

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a template member function declared in a class that call the correct member function depending on type, and want to add some functionality to it in a daughter class, by adding a member function, like in the main.cpp example below :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void handleSocketData(const T& t)
    {
        handleData(t);
    }

    void handleData(int data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

};

class B: public A
{
public :
    void handleData(std::string data) const
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.handleSocketData<int>(30);
    b.handleSocketData<std::string>("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that `b.handleSocketData<QString>("Hi");` actually does generate a new template instance in A class as shown in the output of command `/usr/bin/clang++ -DQT_CORE_LIB -isystem /usr/include/qt6/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/qt6 -isystem /usr/lib64/qt6/mkspecs/linux-g++ -g -std=gnu++17  -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only main.cpp`:

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename T> void handleSocketData(const T &t) {
        this->handleData(t);
    }
    template<> void handleSocketData<int>(const int &t) {
        this->handleData(t);
    }
    template<> void handleSocketData<std::basic_string<char>>(const std::basic_string<char> &t) {
        <recovery-expr>(this->handleData, t);
    }
    void handleData(int data) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void handleData(std::string data) const {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.handleSocketData<int>(30);
    b.handleSocketData<std::string>("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

So right now I have a compilation error, saying that no function handleData(const std::string& data) is found, which is normal.

A workaround we've found is to define a two-arguments template, taking the daughter class as argument (kind of visitor pattern) :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void handleSocketData(U& u, const T& t)
    {
        u.handleData(t);
    }

    void handleData(int data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

};

class B: public A
{
public :
    void handleData(std::string data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.handleSocketData<int>(a, 30);
    b.handleSocketData<std::string>(b, "Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

What do you think ? Is there a cleaner way ?

Comment: Never knew that classes have gender. What if you change it to a son class ?

Comment: Your solution look like [deducing this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) (C++23).

Comment: Am I correct in the assumption, that the templated `handleSocketData` needs to be there for some reasion *(satisfying an external API or whatever)*? Because for the simple example you provided it is not needed because of overload resolution: https://godbolt.org/z/x64osr3M4

Comment: @joergbrech You're correct :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a classic use case for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). You can make `A` a template over a derived class `Derived` and then dispatch function calls to the derived class via a `static_cast`. For this to work, any derived class `Derived` must be derived from `A<Derived>`.

Since you seem to want to use `A` as a non-abstract class, you would have to add a default derived class marking it as "final". In the following code, the empty struct `FinalTag` serves this purpose.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct FinalTag;

template <typename Derived=FinalTag>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void handleSocketData(const T& t)
    {
        cast().handleData(t);
    }

    void handleData(int data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

private:
    constexpr auto& cast() {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }

};

struct FinalTag : A<FinalTag> {};

class B: public A<B>
{
public :
    using Base = A<B>;
    using Base::handleData;

    void handleData(std::string data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.handleSocketData(30);
    b.handleSocketData("Hi");

    // this only works if you bring in Base::handleData in the 
    // derived class
    b.handleSocketData(30);
    return 0;
}
```

Live Code: https://godbolt.org/z/ns9aPjG76

This is a prototype. You would want to add a const version to the `cast` method for instance.

### Edit:

As Jarod42 pointed out in the comments, C++23 really simplifies CRTP with "deducing this": https://godbolt.org/z/cGzMrnEhc. This isn't currently widely supported by compilers though.

Comment: Probably `constexpr auto& cast()` or `constexpr decltype(auto) cast()`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different version of CRTP to the one suggested by Joerg Brech could be more suitable in some cases.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    template <class Class, typename T>
    void handleSocketData(const T& t)
    {
        static_cast<Class*>(this)->handleData(t);
    }

    void handleData(int data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

};

class B: public A
{
public :
    void handleData(std::string data) const
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.handleSocketData<A, int>(30);
    b.handleSocketData<B, std::string>("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

It is very similar to your solution in the sense that we instruct `handleSocketData` which class it should use to call `handleData` from. The only difference is that the decision is made not dynamically but at compile time.

Comment: Better to reverse the template argument order, so `int` might be deduced (`std::string` still required, as `"Hi"` is not a `std::string` (but `const char (&) [3]`)

Comment: Like this solution as well, since it is more simple.